# How can I edit a TableAdapter's stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012, tableadapter

Using Visual Studio 2012 I have created a `TableAdapter` and a corresponding stored procedure which can be accessed via `GetData()`. This was done using the graphical query generator. This works fine but I need to change the query.

Now, this might sound somewhat boring to you but how can I edit this stored procedure for the `GetData()` query? I cannot find a way to open the graphical query generator.

I have found the following description from Microsoft and it says: "The TableAdapter Configuration Wizard opens, ready for you to modify the query or stored procedure that fills the TableAdapter's associated data table."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171902.aspx

I followed the steps but it doesn't allow editing the select statements etc. itself.

Comment: Maybe override it by extending the class?

Comment: @leeand00 Sorry, my question was a little bit unclear. I'm looking for a way to edit the query with the graphical query generator.

Comment: @Robert Why can't you edit the SQL by hand?

Comment: @Yuck That's the point. The queries are rather complex so I have used the editor. But even when editing the SQL manually I cannot find where to do that.

Comment: @Robert So just use Visio or Dia to map out your query and the joins between tables...

Comment: @Robert Quite the contrary, if the query is complex that's all the more reason **not** to use a query designer.

Comment: Yeah, however the question is *where* to edit the query? I searched the complete project solution for SQL statements but cannot find any :-)

Comment: try ServerExplorer tab, choose yoour database -> stored procedures and edit it there. Or you can use SQLManagementStudio.

Comment: Are you able to open the .xsd file, located in the Solution Explorer for your project?

Comment: Not seeing the wood for the trees... the procedures themselves are, of course, located in the database. Not in the code. No wonder I couldn't find anything :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statements are located in the database, not in the code or in the Visual Studio project. So, changing the statements in the database should do it.